# Craft Commerce: Displaying Individual Product Options in the Cart?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

In the cart example code the selected options are displayed in an unformatted list like so:

```
{{ item.options|json_encode }}
```

I noticed that the note field text could be outputted individually like so:

```
{{ item.note }}
```

I'm looking to do the same for the select fields on my product, so if I had a list of options like the gift wrap example, how would I then output the result individually (so that I can format how I like)?

```
<select name="options[giftWrapped]">
  <option value="no">No gift wrap.</option>
  <option value="yes">Gift wrapped.</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is the example code for the cart:

```
{{ item.options.giftWrapped }}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also loop through each object within the `options` array using:

```
{% for key, value in item.options %}
  {{ key }} - {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```